# nth-of-type only working for 1 and 2

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a styling problem, I am using WordPress and want to do have the first two classes completely different to the others.

My ideal situation is to have:

```
.si-biplace:nth-of-type(3) { float:left; margin:20px 0px 0px 0px; }
.si-image:nth-of-type(3) { float:left; margin:20px 0px 0px 0px; border:0px; }
.si-title:nth-of-type(3) { width:100px; height:20px; margin:0px; font-size:7px; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; }
```

They seem to work fine when it is:

```
.si-biplace { float:left; margin:-10px 0px 0px 0px; }
.si-biplace:nth-of-type(2) { float:left; margin:-10px 0px 0px 15px; }
```

Is there a reason why it will not work with nth-of-type(3) but will with nth of type 2? I basically want different attributes for every next time the div is used but cannot have separate div classes as it runs through a php array.

Here is my HTML & PHP Structure incase I am doing something wrong:

```
<div class="si-biplace">
    <div class="si-image">
        <a href="http://universitycompare.com:8888/945/test/">
        <img width="340" height="170" src="http://universitycompare.com:8888/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/post-test.png" class="attachment-si-images wp-post-image" alt="post-test" title="post-test"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="si-title">
        <a href="http://universitycompare.com:8888/945/test/">Testing Post Article Number1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="si-date">
        &nbsp;Date:&nbsp; <a style="color:#154157;" href="http://universitycompare.com:8888/945/test/">
        September 6, 2012 </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="si-biplace">
    <div class="si-image">
        <a href="http://universitycompare.com:8888/28/what-graduates-need-to-know-about-creative-internships/">
        <img width="340" height="170" src="http://universitycompare.com:8888/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/post-test.png" class="attachment-si-images wp-post-image" alt="post-test" title="post-test"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="si-title">
        <a href="http://universitycompare.com:8888/28/what-graduates-need-to-know-about-creative-internships/">What graduates need to know about creative internships</a>
    </div>
    <div class="si-date">
        &nbsp;Date:&nbsp; <a style="color:#154157;" href="http://universitycompare.com:8888/28/what-graduates-need-to-know-about-creative-internships/">
        July 3, 2012 </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="si-biplace">
    <div class="si-image">
        <a href="http://universitycompare.com:8888/25/students-say-they-will-work-for-free-after-graduating/">
        <img width="340" height="170" src="http://universitycompare.com:8888/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/post-test.png" class="attachment-si-images wp-post-image" alt="post-test" title="post-test"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="si-title">
        <a href="http://universitycompare.com:8888/25/students-say-they-will-work-for-free-after-graduating/">Students say they will work for free after graduating</a>
    </div>
    <div class="si-date">
        &nbsp;Date:&nbsp; <a style="color:#154157;" href="http://universitycompare.com:8888/25/students-say-they-will-work-for-free-after-graduating/">
        July 3, 2012 </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I have just updated my question with my HTML structure incase that is wrong based on my css?

Comment: It's always better to include the *generated* HTML from your browser's "View Source" option than the PHP, which could be generating *anything* as far as we're concerned

Comment: @Gareth - i have just Done that - does that help?

Comment: Is it possible that there are only 2 present? Because it should work. Unless it is a browser issue. nth-type-of is CSS3 so it only works in modern browsers. However if you are getting results for 2 then I suspect that is not the issue. But it should work... check out this fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/kqS3d/

Comment: [`:nth-of-type(3)`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gHEKK/) certainly works. Something else is going wrong.

Comment: Is it not working on all three of your selectors?

Comment: It works on the first two, not the third...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To style the first two elements in a class differently from the others, it is best to set general style settings for the class and then override them as desired for the first two.

If you for some reason wish to do it by setting some styles for the 3rd, 4th, 5th etc. child of an element, you can use `:nth-child(n+3)`, and to refer to the 3rd, 4th, 5th etc. child of its kinf of an element, use `:nth-of-type(n+3)`. This can be combined with a class selector, but it does *not* mean referring to nth element in a class.

In your case, assuming there is no other `div` element before these elements, you could thus use

```
.si-biplace:nth-of-type(n+3) { ... }
.si-biplace:nth-of-type(n+3) .si-image { ... }
.si-biplace:nth-of-type(n+3) .si-title { ... }
```

You cannot use constructs like `.si-image:nth-of-type(3)`, because in your markup, each element in class `.si-image` is the first child of its parent and therefore never matches the selector.

Comment: Yup this is right! After ages and ages of working out I did do it this way! Just, based on my reputation wasn't able to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I have reproduced your problem.. It looks like you need to use :nth-child() for the elements inside of the "si-biplace" divs.

**Here is my CSS from my fiddle..**

```
.biplace:nth-of-type(3){
    float:left; margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;   
}


.biplace:nth-of-type(3) .image:nth-child(3){
    float:left; margin:20px 0px 0px 0px; border:0px; 
}

.biplace:nth-of-type(3) .title:nth-child(3){
    width:100px; height:20px; margin:0px; font-size:7px; color:red; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid red; 
}
```

**And some HTML, it should be the same as your structure...**

```
   <p class="image">Something</p>
   <p class="image">Something</p>

   <h2 class="title">First Title</h2>
</div>




 <div class="biplace">
   <p class="image">Something</p>
   <p class="image">Something</p>

     <h2 class="title">Second Title</h2>
</div>




 <div class="biplace">
   <p class="image">Something</p>
   <p class="image">Something</p>

     <h2 class="title">Third Title</h2>
</div>
```

**Here is a fiddle I started to reproduce the problem.**

http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/sFkLz/6/

**And and article which talks about the difference of both in more detail...**

http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/